# Can I configure a @FeignClient url using a properties/yml file?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-feign

My goal is to create a strategy of different steps to get from a point-to-point communication between 2 components to a "full blown netflix" style of communication using eureka, ribbon, hystrix. With each iteration I want to add more while I try to limit the amount of changes to the actual code. Feign is my preferred client side framework to make this happen. First step is to create a FeignClient to communicate to the server:

```
@FeignClient(url = "http://localhost:9000")
interface Client {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/author/{author}/addedValue/{addedValue}")
    Result addToTotal(@RequestParam(value="author") String author, @RequestParam(value="addedValue") long addedValue);
}
```

This works but I don't want the URL to be hardcoded in the annotation. I would like to have this: @FeignClient()
and have a properties construct like: client.url: http://localhost:9000

So far I couldn't find any clues on how to configure that and I couldn't find a solution in the spring-cloud sources.

Can it be done and if yes; how?

Comment: hope this answer can help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43733569/how-can-i-change-the-feign-url-during-the-runtime/54455735#54455735](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43733569/how-can-i-change-the-feign-url-during-the-runtime/54455735#54455735)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It can be done with a "serviceId" instead of a "url". E.g.

```
@FeignClient("foo")
interface Client { ... }
```

and

```
foo.ribbon.listOfServers: localhost:9000
```

e.g. see http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#spring-cloud-ribbon-without-eureka for docs.

Comment: Generally it's not if it's used to bind to Spring Boot `@ConfigurationPoperties` but this is still Netflix native.

Comment: I tried it but I have the following error: `com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: foo`. Note: I use an `application.yml` and not `application.properties`

Comment: You probably got the YAML format wrong then. Or I didn't understand the question.

Comment: @Pleymor, I had the same issue and had to set `ribbon.eureka.enabled=false` to get Ribbon to use the configuration-based server list. I am using rather old versions of the Spring Cloud libraries (1.0.0.RELEASE) and Netflix stuff (feign-ribbon 7.1.0 and ribbon 2.0-RC13), though. Maybe this has been changed in newer versions

Comment: What if you have a base URL for all feign clients like "/api"?

Answer (score 45):

This can be done like this:

```
@FeignClient(name="fd-mobileapi-service",url="${fdmobile.ribbon.listOfServers}")
```

Where `fdmobile.ribbon.listOfServers : value` is a property in `application.properties`.

I have tested it and it is working.

Comment: Not true if you have multiple servers in your list of servers. This hardcodes only one url, and takes listOfServers as a single value.

Comment: This worked just fine for us as we needed this only for local environment, for other envs we are using Eureka , so the name suffices

Comment: Can this be accomplished within the RequestLine annotation?

Answer (score 0):

I got a way to pass the environment variables in a very simple way interface FeignClient,

```
    @FeignClient(url = "https://"+"\${url}")
    interface Client {
    
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/author/{author}/addedValue/{addedValue}")
    Result addToTotal(@RequestParam(value="author") String author, @RequestParam(value="addedValue") long addedValue);
```

properties

```
#URL
url.client=${URL}
```

.env

```
URL=https:localhost:9000
```

Comment: It doesn't work
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Either 'name' or 'value' must be provided in @FeignClient`

Comment: you must add the name property to feignCliente, as in the new version this is required
`@FeignClient(url = "https:/\${url}", name = "Cadastro", decode404 = true)`