# consume a REST service from the outside world behind a corporate proxy with authentication

Tags: spring, rest, proxy, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I want to consume a REST service from the outside world behind a corporate proxy with authentication. How do I configure Spring Cloud Feign to use our proxy? Note: I'm using feign spring boot implementation, I do not need to make a builder for Feign "Feign.builder () ...", since it's built automatically by spring? I've been looking for this solution to make requests to addresses through the corporate proxy for quite a while and have not found anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do something like this:

```
@FeignClient(url="${service.url}")
public interface MyClient {
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/item/{idItem}", consumes = "application/json",
        headers="Authorization: Basic ${service.auth}")
public Item getItem(@PathVariable("idItem") int idItem);
}
```

as described here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/288

These are also relevant if you don't want to hard code headers and url:

[Can I configure a @FeignClient url using a properties/yml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278005/can-i-configure-a-feignclient-url-using-a-properties-yml-file)

[Using @Headers with dynamic values in Feign client + Spring Cloud (Brixton RC2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066331/using-headers-with-dynamic-values-in-feign-client-spring-cloud-brixton-rc2)

Comment: That way I can make requests to addresses outside my network even though I'm inside a network with a proxy?

Comment: Ah sorry, you also need to configure feign like this feign.okhttp.enabled=true.

Comment: I did what you said but this is giving error here after inserting the option: headers = "Authorization: Basic http://proxy.com:8080". Now I can not start the system start, the following error was generated:
 String index out of range: -1

Comment: headers = "Authorization: Basic proxy.com:8080" is not correct. You should put there (${service.auth}) your authentication token (not the url) if you use authentication. If you do not use authentication, just delete the "headers" part.