# Inject property value into feignclient annotation

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, feign

I have my Jhipster config/ApplicationProperties.java class setup and working however it's not clear how to inject a property value into the FeignClient annotation for the url:

```
@FeignClient(
  name="myApi",
  url="how do I inject an application.yml property here?",
  configuration="MyConfig.class")
```

Using @Value doesn't work per below:

```
@FeignClient(
  name="myApi",
  url=@Value("${application.api.url}"),
  configuration="MyConfig.class")
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: May be here is an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278005/can-i-configure-a-feignclient-url-using-a-properties-yml-file

Comment: I figured it out: url="{application.api.url:}". The trailing semi-colon was needed. Thanks @AlexeyUsharovski

Comment: I don’t think the : is required, just using the usual “${app.prop}” works

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
@FeignClient(
  name="myApi",
  url="${application.api.url}",
  configuration="MyConfig.class")
```